# Scrollbar problems in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a fixed-width content area using margin:0 auto to keep it centered and a repeating background that fills the whole page.  Nothing should cause the browser to use a horizontal scrollbar, unless the browser is less than browser is less than the fixed-width content.  In IE however, a horizontal scrollbar is present and allows me to scroll slightly to the right which displays a 'gap' that appears to be the width of the vertical scrollbar.  Curious as to why this is happening.

I have searched far and wide and found people with similar problems, but most discussion is regarding tables or other specific elements causing the problem that are not present on my page.

See link for example, open in IE8 and scroll right. Any help is appreciated.

http://finchsbrasserie.com/test_new_site/

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but when I open your link in IE8 no scrollbar is present.

Comment: You should add the screen resolution on which the scrollbars appear. I think you mean at 1024x768px?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the div css propety as overflow-x:hidden